# Better keyboard control in shell

Tags: command-line, vim

I work a lot in vim and the thing that frustrates me is when I have to switch to the shell, that I lose a lot of the keyboard control that vim has.

For example I have to use home and end to get to beginning and end of the line.

How do you deal with this annoyance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Bash manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/bash.1.html), Bash natively supports a "vi-style command line editing interface". To use it, add `set -o vi` to your `~/.bashrc` file.

By default you'll be in input mode; press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter command mode. [This cheatsheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt) lists the commands available to you.

Comment: That's so awesome.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Home` and `End` in Vim too.
2. Learn all the shortcuts there are in the shell.

Usually, Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E go to the beginning and end of the line, respectively. You can define any number of shortcuts in your `.inputrc` file, and even switch to vi-mode. Try `man bash` and look for `READLINE`.

Comment: By default bash uses emacs text editing mode. You can set it to vi-mode as ændrük, if you're used to vi that's probably easier.